# Create a .CSS, .HTML and .JS file using Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

*I am quite new to Node and hence stuck with this!!*

I am trying to write a node script that makes a folder (lizardproject) which has three different files i.e. index.html, app.js, style.css.

**Code**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const folderName = process.argv[2] || 'Project'

try {
fs.mkdirSync(folderName);
fs.writeFileSync(`${folderName}/index.html`)
fs.writeFileSync(`${folderName}/app.js`)
fs.writeFileSync(`${folderName}/style.css`)
} catch(e) {
    console.log("Something went wrong!!");
    console.log(e);
}
```

On execution, the folder is being created.

**Execution**

```
hp\nodeintro>node boilerplate.js lizardproject
```

**Result**

```
hp\nodeintro>ls
boilerplate.js   lizardproject
```

But the files are not, and this error is being displayed:-

**Error**

> Something went wrong!!
> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined
> at Object.writeFileSync

Comment: [`writeFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fswritefilesyncfile-data-options) accepts two arguments. Filename and data. You didn't pass any data.

Comment: You need to write something when using writeFile(Sync). Just add a second argument with an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fswritefilesyncfile-data-options) for that function:

> fs.writeFileSync(file, data[, options])
>
> ```
> file <string> | <Buffer> | <URL> | <integer> filename or file descriptor
> data <string> | <Buffer> | <TypedArray> | <DataView> | <Object>
> ```

`data` is the second argument.

You aren't providing the second argument so it is `undefined`. Hence the error message: **Received undefined at Object.writeFileSync**.

The error tells you what types of values are acceptable. Provide one of those. A string would be simplest.